# How to update state in react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have made a submit form. I have made userReducer where `user[]` is array and each array element has `firstname`, `lastname`,`emailid` etc. When I click on submit button it shows array element [0] but when I click on clear button and again try to fill in the form and try to submit no user is added again i.e no state is updated. How to fix this problem ?

Form component (form.js) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as action from '../actions/actions';


import './form.css';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setFirstName = this.setFirstName.bind(this);
    this.setLastName = this.setLastName.bind(this);
    this.setEmailId = this.setEmailId.bind(this);
    this.setIban = this.setIban.bind(this);
    this.setBankName = this.setBankName.bind(this);
    this.showUser = this.showUser.bind(this);
    this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);

     console.log(this.props);

    }

    setFirstName(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setFirstName(event.target.value));
    }

    setLastName(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setLastName(event.target.value));
    }

    setEmailId(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setEmailId(event.target.value));
    }

    setIban(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setIban(event.target.value));
    }

    setBankName(event) {
    this.props.dispatch(action.setBankName(event.target.value));
    }

    showUser(){
        const jsonobj = this.props;
        alert(JSON.stringify(jsonobj));
    }

    reset(){
        this.props.dispatch(action.setFirstName(''));
        this.props.dispatch(action.setLastName(''));
        this.props.dispatch(action.setEmailId(''));
        this.props.dispatch(action.setIban(''));
        this.props.dispatch(action.setBankName(''));
    }


  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <div id="center">
              <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                         <label htmlFor="firstname">First Name:</label>
                         <input type="firstname" className="form-control" id="firstname" value={this.props.firstname} onChange={this.setFirstName} required/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                         <label htmlFor="lastname">Last Name:</label>
                         <input type="lastname" className="form-control" id="lastname" value={this.props.lastname} onChange={this.setLastName} required/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="email">Email address:</label>
                        <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" value={this.props.emailid} onChange={this.setEmailId} required/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                         <label htmlFor="bankacc">IBAN:</label>
                         <div id="deletebank" className="items">
                         <input type="bankacc" className="form-control" id="bankacc" value={this.props.iban} onChange={this.setIban} required/>
                         <button type="button" className="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> 
                         </button>
                         </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                         <label htmlFor="bankname">Bank Name:</label>
                         <input type="bankname" className="form-control" id="bankname" value={this.props.bankname} onChange={this.setBankName} required/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div id="buttons" className="items">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick={this.reset}>Clear Input</button>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.showUser}>Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>


              </form>
          </div>
      </div>

    )}


}

const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return {
    firstname: store.user.firstname,
    lastname: store.user.lastname,
    emailid: store.user.emailid,
    iban: store.user.iban,
    bankname: store.user.bankname
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Form);
```

reducer.js:

```
const userReducer = (state = {
  user:[{
    firstname:'',
    lastname:'',
    emailid:'',
    bankaccounts:{
      iban:'',
      bankname:''
    }
  }]
  }, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_FIRSTNAME':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, firstname: action.payload}
      }
    }

    case 'SET_LASTNAME':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, lastname: action.payload}
      }
    }

    case 'SET_EMAILID':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, emailid: action.payload}
      }
    }

    case 'SET_IBAN':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, iban: action.payload}
      }
    }

    case 'SET_BANKNAME':{
      return {
        ...state,
        user:{...state.user, bankname: action.payload}
      }
    }
    default: return state;
  }

}

export default userReducer;
```

Actions.js:

```
export const SET_FIRSTNAME = 'SET_FIRSTNAME';
export const SET_LASTNAME = 'SET_LASTNAME';
export const SET_EMAILID = 'SET_EMAILID';
export const SET_IBAN = 'SET_IBAN';
export const SET_BANKNAME = 'SET_BANKNAME';


export function setFirstName(firstname){
    return {
        type:SET_FIRSTNAME,
        payload:firstname
    }
}

export function setLastName(lastname){
    return {
        type:SET_LASTNAME,
        payload:lastname
    }
}

export function setEmailId(emailid){
    return {
        type:SET_EMAILID,
        payload:emailid
    }
}

export function setIban(iban){
    return {
        type:SET_IBAN,
        payload:iban
    }
}

export function setBankName(bankname){
    return {
        type:SET_BANKNAME,
        payload:bankname
    }
}
```

store.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import userReducer from './reducers/reducers';


const store = createStore(userReducer);

store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Store changed', store.getState());
})

export default store;
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: your initialState doesn't match what your reducer switch statements return... in your initial state `user` is an array of objects (should probably be called "users" then.. but your reducers return `user: {}` I wouldn't be surprised if your pages initial load form wasn't getting any values

Comment: also do you really need an action and a method for EVERY key? if you add more keys or remove keys you'll have so much code to change. maybe just one function and one switch statement where you pass the key along

Comment: @azium I could not understand how to fix that problem. Please check my question I have added actions.js

Comment: why you are not using Object.assign() in your reducer to avoid state mutation..?

Comment: @MukulSharma op is using the spread operator, no need for `Object.assign`

Comment: @MukulSharma state mutation is not an issue here I guess.

Comment: @stonerock so is `user` supposed to be an array like it is in your initialstate or are you just supposed to have a single user object?

Comment: @azium State should be user array and each user array element should have email, lastname, firstname,etc

Comment: can you also how the code for where you create the store? are you using `combineReducers`?

Comment: @azium I have edited question please check store.js. Can you tell me how to create user reducer where I want user array and not user object. Everytime I submit form it should create multiple objects of user but in my case it is not happening.

Comment: @azium Did you got what I am trying to do ? I want user list i.e user array and each user should have firstname, lastname, emailid, etc.

Comment: Yeah I'm writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of stuff to address here, but the primary issue is that your state is expecting `user` to be an array. I think it would be very wise to rename this `users` as to not get confused:

(I'm going to remove some keys to make this easier)

```
const initialState = {
  users: [ // note "users" not "user"
    {
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
    },
  ],
};
```

Your reducer switch statements don't specify WHICH user it should be updating. If you want to just start with "adding" a new user it might look something like this:

```
const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_USER": {
      return {
        ...state,
        users: [...state.users, action.payload],
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Here we add a new user to the `users` array in the form of `action.payload` which should contain all the keys you want on your user.

You can now have an action creator that's a bit more concise

```
const addUser = user => ({
  type: 'ADD_USER',
  payload: user,
})
```

And your form could be simplified a lot:

```
import * as actions from './actions'

class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: '',
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={() => {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.addUser(this.state))
      }}>
        <input 
          value={this.state.firstname} 
          onChange={e => this.setState({ firstname: e.target.value })
        />
        <input 
          value={this.state.lastname} 
          onChange={e => this.setState({ lastname: e.target.value })
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default connect()(Form)
```

Comment: Got it thanks. The state variables created in form component are local state am I right ?

Comment: correct. you might need something slightly different if you're editing user information from a form. come back here if you're having trouble with that and can update answer to include updating a user.. there are lots of blog posts that address that though

Comment: I want to delete particular user by filling `iban` input field that's why I have created `trash` icon after `Iban`. This can be done using `map()` is it possible ? Also can you share some blog links which demonstrate such examples.